# how to add a new font to tinymce editor

Tags: fonts, tinymce, font-face, tinymce-4

I want to add a new font in TinyMCE editor which are display in font dropdown and apply to edit text.
I have used a direct link I am new to PHP I have done some online research but most people post the insert the font in TinyMCE folder but I do not have the folder I used the direct link

Answer (score 0):

In TinyMCE you can control what fonts are displayed in the font dropdown using the `font_formats:` configuration option:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'fontselect',
  font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace'
});
```

Note that fonts may be applied to editor content via the `content_css` or `content_style` configuration options. However, for fonts to show in the `fontselect` dropdown they must be defined in the `font_formats` configuration option.

Here's some more information about font and `font_formats:` in TinyMCE:

[Font Formats](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#font_formats)

[Content CSS](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css)

[Content Style](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style)